# DataFrame structure conversion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a structure and want to convert it to another structure.

[image: DataFrame before and after]

I tried the pivot method but all I could see was NaN values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['variableType'] = df['firstName'] + '_' + df['names']
pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['variableType'], values='variableValue', columns=['variableName'])
pvt

variableName  varX  varY
variableType            
abc123_v_001   1.0   3.0
abc123_v_002   2.0   4.0
efg456_v_001   1.0   3.0
efg456_v_002   2.0   4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get the required structure. Just a quick question, what if I want some values to be filled for the variableType row ie below the varX and varY columns.